# SelectedIndex_ Changed not getting fired!

Tags: asp.net

SelectedIndex_Changed event occurs when selection changes, and selection is changed or not is decided by comparing dropdowns current selectedIndex and its value in viewstate.

When we changes dropdown's selected Item using Javascript, it does not change the viewstate's value (which is previously selectedIndex). Now if you change dropdown's selectedIndex to any new index it will work fine, but if you select the previously selectedIndex (which we reset using javascript), then postback will occur, but selectedIndex_changed function will not get fired because in viewstate of dropdown, selectedIndex is same as the Index we select after resetting it using javascript.

I need to look for some solution to tackle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is by-design of the control.  If you select the same index, then the index has not changed.  If the index has not changed, then why would the SelectedIndex_**Changed** event fire?